# i want the the text to be shown besides the icon image and not below it

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

Here, in the following code, the text in `<p></p>` gets displayed below the icon in the div. I want this `<p>` to appear within the div beside the icon image. Also, I want the  `<div>` tags to be positioned at the bottom of the page.

Here is my code.

```
<body>
    <input type="date">Date</input>
<input type="number">Fs</input>
<input type="number">PtP</input>
<br/><br/>

<div id="add"><img src="iconic\vector\plus_alt.svg"><p>Add</p></div>
<div id="show"><img src="iconic\vector\eye.svg" title="see"><p>Show</p></div>
<div id="showAll"><img src="iconic\vector\list.svg"><p>Show All</p></div>
<div id="delete"><img src="iconic\vector\trash_stroke.svg"><p>Clear All</p></div>
</body>
```

Here css

```
#add 
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px
}
#add
{

 width: 25%;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
   background-color:#ffcc00;opacity:0.75;
}
#add  p
{font-size:15px;
position: inline;
visibility:hidden
}
#add:hover  p
{
visibility:visible;
}



#show
{
  width: 25%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color:#ffcc00;opacity:0.75;

}
#show p
{font-size:15px;
position: inline;
visibility:hidden
}
#show:hover p
{
visibility:visible;
}


#showAll
{
  width: 25%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color:#ffcc00;opacity:0.75;

}
#showAll p
{font-size:15px;
position: inline;
visibility:hidden
}
#showAll:hover  p
{
visibility:visible;
}


#delete
{
  width: 25%;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
 background-color:#ffcc00;opacity:0.75;
}
#delete p
{font-size:15px;
position: relative;
visibility:hidden
}
#delete:hover  p
{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: increasing width of the containing div should allow your text to show after the image.

Comment: Your title says to position the test **besides** the icon not **on top** of the icon

Comment: ...in any case ...I have aligned the text better here: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sCEqC/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css code is rather verbose.

I think this is what you're looking for

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sCEqC/1/)**

```
div
{

 width: 25%;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
 background-color:#ffcc00;opacity:0.75;
}
p
{
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline;
    visibility:hidden;
}

div:hover p
{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: @ Danield...yeah that is fyn...thnx...but how can i position the p such that the text appears above the icon..

Answer (score 0):

At first, there is no need to write the same `style` for each `element` using its `ID`. You can simply give them the same `class name` and style only using `class name`. The second, I'm suggesting you to use `UL` tag to make a navigation menu. And finally, you can achieve the effect you want using `float` property. I've updated your original code and here is the demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcnDk/).

P.S. Ask me, if something is not clear for you.

Comment: @ Karlen Kishmiryan...tnx:) almost 90% job done beautifully...but there appear some boundaries between the list items how to remove these ...i want a seamless div containing 4 icons.. Secondly i want that this nav panel of 4 li get fixed to bottom of page whatever be the screen size... help

Comment: And what kind of boundaries do you mean?

Comment: For fixing, you just need to add these lines to the `style` under `ul.nav selector`: `position: fixed;` `width: 100%;` `left: 0px;` and also set `margin: 0px;`. Here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/UcnDk/3/

Comment: these kind of boundaries appear..   http://s22.postimg.org/47twzsxi9/boundaries.jpg   http://postimg.org/image/npokfqufx/

Comment: Hmm.. The border comes from other styles, which you've already included in your file. If you don't know from where it comes, try to clear borders explicitly. In your CSS file add the following selector: `ul.nav li` and add this line under it: `border: none !important;` Here is the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UcnDk/4/

Comment: yes..but i want that the text should appear above the image so that there are no issues of overflow when screen size decrease...this is last question...we are nearly there...

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution if everything is works for you.